# Swagger for PHP array of arrays

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I am trying to create a response example that should return an array like this:

```
[
  [
    "Shop Name",
    "53.7094190",
    "-1.9084720"
    ,1
  ]
]
```

For this I am using this code:

```
*   @OA\Response(
*     response= "default",
*     description="Success: Array of shops",
*     @OA\MediaType(
*       mediaType="text/plain",
*         @OA\Schema(
*           type = "array",
*           @OA\Items( type="array",
*              @OA\Items(type="string", default="'Bridge Balti','53.7094190','-1.9084720',1"),
*           ),
*         )
*     )
*   )
```

And I am getting this in swagger hub:

```
[
  [
    "string"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display an example in swagger ui, then you need to use the "example" parameter.

@OA\Items(type="string",example="'Bridge Balti','53.7094190','-1.9084720',1")

Comment: I'm trying this solution but somehow it ends as a single item for me:
      "test": [
        "'Bridge Balti','53.7094190','-1.9084720',1"
      ]
Any chance I might be doing it differently?

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doen't work for me. Instead of array, it was showing as string.
Following change works for me. ( Double quotes does the magic )

```
example="[""Bridge Balti"",""53.7094190"",""-1.9084720"",1]"
```